# PostMessage unexpected behaviour

Tags: c#, postmessage

I'm having a funny ol' time with PostMessage, wondering if anybody could enlighten me.

The method below processes the first left click but not the second, I did a bit of messing around and found that using a MessageBox and hitting OK even instantly provides the delay/release or whatever it is that's needed to make the second left click process.

```
public void MouseClick(IntPtr handle)
{
    PostMessage(handle, (uint)WMessages.WM_LBUTTONDOWN, 0, MAKELPARAM(521, 147));
    PostMessage(handle, (uint)WMessages.WM_LBUTTONUP, 0, MAKELPARAM(521, 147));
    //MessageBox.Show("WAITING...");
    PostMessage(handle, (uint)WMessages.WM_LBUTTONDOWN, 0, MAKELPARAM(675, 527));
    PostMessage(handle, (uint)WMessages.WM_LBUTTONUP, 0, MAKELPARAM(675, 527));
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/05/30/423202.aspx

Comment: Do you want double clock?

Comment: Your declaration for PostMessage is wrong, no way the 3rd argument can be 0.  Other than that, surely it is quirk of the program you are trying to commandeer.

Comment: @HansPassant The third parameter for `PostMessage` is `WPARAM wParam`, why can't that be 0?

Comment: Because the equivalent C# type is IntPtr and you can't pass 0 for an argument of type IntPtr.

Answer (score -2):

That is because the main thread message pump is suspended while you are in the MouseClick function. The messagebox call re-enables the message pump. What you can do is call Application.DoEvents or do it in another thread.